# Error: Authority expected at index 7: http://...!!! Explain please?

Tags: java, android

I have a url for JSON feeds that i have to fetch from and then parse them to save in my DB. But i am getting the following error in the url when i try to make request to this url using HttpGet method. This Url show the json feeds fine when i open it in browser. For privacy reason i am not posting the original url rather a dummy one.

URL is like:

```
 http://api.test.com/services/json?method=%22cviews.get%22&view_name=%22section_gallery_slides%22&display_id=%22attachment_1%22&format_output=1&args=[123456]&limit=10
```

and Error i am getting is:

```
10-18 12:29:10.510: DEBUG/ImageManager(22082): Error: java.io.IOException: Authority expected at index 7: http://
```

Please tell me what's going wrong and where, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066460/javaandroid-ioexception-authority-expected-at-index-7-http

Comment: Please post some code and the full StackTrace.

Comment: Your privacy reasons gave us an URL that's valid, while the one you actually use is not. What's the host/authority and path of your actual URL? Might be a `/` missing in there.

Comment: @Phillip Reichart, i have just changed the text in the above url, other than that whole url's structure is same as the original one.