# java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7: http://

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting error:

> Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7:
>   http://

For below code:

```
try 
{
    return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + username + ":" + authkey +"@hub.crossbrowsertesting.com:80/wd/hub"), caps);
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
 }
```

Stack trace:

> Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
>         at abc.testcase.LoginForm2.main(LoginForm2.java:45)
>       Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>         ... 4 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: Cannot convert host to URI: http://
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:77)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:77)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:124)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:183)
>         ... 12 more
>       Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7: http://
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3102)
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
>         at java.net.URI.(URI.java:588)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:75)
>         ... 15 more

Please help!

Comment: please Show the Content of the concatinated string

Comment: username:xyz@abc.com and authkey:abc12cd34

Comment: I got sample code at https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/getting-started/java/

Comment: @Jens can you please check for me.

Comment: You are sure you Import the correct URL class? `import java.net.URL;`?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Yes, import java.net.URL

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066460/javaandroid-ioexception-authority-expected-at-index-7-http

Comment: It gives error if i encode url:java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Comment: Thanks @Jens for hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error got resolved just by encoding @ by %40